# Way to send large number of push notifications

Tags: grails, scalability

I'm using grails to make the back office of a mobile application.
in this application we can send push notifications to all connected devices ( ios and android).

now am just making a for loop on users for sending push notifications to all devices.

So, my question is , if i have a large number of devices ( hundred of thousands or even millions ).

how can i send this push notification to all users instantly ( i think with my for loop it can take too much time )

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you investigate the use of distributing the contents of your list into a JMS queue as individual messages. From there you can have N number of consumers reading from the queue and sending your notifications. This is a fairly typical pattern for sending notifications and scales very well.